# Can we declare the constructor static to make a singleton class? java

Tags: java, oop, singleton

```
class SomeClass{
    static SomeClass(){
    }
}
```

Here, although we maybe able to create different names, but shouldn't it refer to the same memory location? Analogous to calling the same person once by his proper name, once his nickname? Would it still be a singleton class?

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: nope....make the constructor private

Comment: A static constructor would not make sense. And why would that make the object a singleton?

Comment: No I know that question is there. I am just thinking about an alternative method for this.

Comment: Eclipse is giving error on static constructor. Are we not allowed static constructors?

Comment: A static "constructor" (initializer) looks like this `static { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: There is no such thing as a static constructor.

Comment: To all the experts here, I can search for the code snippet anywhere. I am asking my own doubt here. If you can't explain this particular doubt, refrain from answering it.

Comment: If it doesn't compile then obviously it's not an alternative method. Stackoverflow is not a brainstorming session.

Comment: @SeanBright  thanks. A little more elaboration would be appreciated ( if there is any).

Comment: @MightyPhoenix17, your question and follow up comments do not indicate a sufficient understanding of Java to warrant continued discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a `static` constructor as it's job is to initialise a `this` instance object.

In Scala you can write

```
object SomeClass {

}
```

To create something between a singleton and static fields of a class.

The simplest way to define a singleton in Java is to use an `enum`

```
enum SomeClass {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

All references to `SomeClass.INSTANCE` will be the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to create and publish a singleton, assuming you don't want to use an implicit singleton (like an `enum`):

```
public SomeClass
{
    private static class SingletonHolder
    {
        public static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();
    }

    public static SomeClass getInstance()
    {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private SomeClass()
    {
    }
}
```